# Is is possible to have a slide effect in RAP Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I'm building a demo site about server management, I have a requirement as following:
- User can search servers when he input an IP certain range, the site will list all information of available servers respectively (Server name, IP , status, usage...). 
I used a TableViewer to show the search result, and I also used pagination. I have 2 buttons Next ans Previous to move among pages. 
The problem I'm facing is how to move automatically among pages with slide effect ( similar as we see photos of an album). When I click Next and Previous buttons, the effect must be the same.
I don't know if RAP can do it and how to do it? 
I'd appreciate for any suggestion or answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer in the RAP Forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/357538/